# Does Algolia have a boost score feature like Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, algolia

I have a requirement on sorting a field which is when a value matches its field, then this document has a higher score than other documents. Can Algolia do this?

Comment: Obviously not quite the same, but you can tell the Algolia the searchable fields and there order of importance.

Answer (score 0):

To reflect the importance of an attribute compared to another, the way to go using Algolia is definitely to **order the attributes** you want to search in in the `searchableAttributes` index setting.

For instance, if you want to search in both `title` and `description`, but `title` is more important; you should go for:

```
searchableAttributes:
 - title
 - description
```

**Compared to the boosting** approach, this ensures the number of match occurrences you have won't impact the overall ranking (common issue in ES is: is 4 words matching here and there in `description` better than 2 words matching exactly in `title`?).

**With Algolia**, the objects matching the longest expression (in terms of proximity between query words in the text) will always be used to identify the best matching attribute; and then to sort the results according to the attributes importance.